# Print JSON data to HTML div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my console log displays all the information properly so I know my codes working, but now I want to output the data to a certain div in my HTML to display the playlist's songs that are being played. How do I print the JSON data from sound[i].title to a div?

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function(){
    $("#{STORIES.story_id}6 :image").removeClass('buyy')
        .removeClass('buyyy')
        .addClass('buy');

    widget.getSounds(function(sound) {
        var a = sound.length;
        for(var i=0; i<a; i++){
            console.log(sound[i].title);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacking any information about where in the DOM tree you'd actually like to put the data...

```
$('#someElement').append($('<div>', {text: sound[i].title }));
```

Comment: Also how can i get it to display in a horizontal list as opposed to a monster vertical list?

Comment: Use an inline element instead of a block-level one.

Answer (score 0):

In many modern browsers, using jQuery, you can do the following:

```
$('#myDiv').text(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

Also, if you would like the JSON to be formatted you can use:

```
JSON.stringify(myJson, undefined, 2);
// JSON -------^       ^          ^
// no filter ----------^          ^
// indent two spaces -------------^
```

Comment: Or to make it pretty `JSON.stringify(myJson, null, 2)`

Comment: I think the OP didn't actually mean printing the JSON itself – just a poorly-worded question.

Comment: @MattBall I think you are right, I think he actually meant the string in `.title` now that I re-read it.

Comment: @MattBall: ah yes, I think you've read the question more carefully ;-)  Upvoting your answer...

Comment: Okay I did this and placed it just under my console.log(sound[i].title); but it will only display the last song. Why wont it display all 25 elements in the object?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //stuff and more stuff//

   for(var i=0; i<a; i++){
      document.getElementById('myList').append= sound[i].title+', ';
    }

</script>
<p>My playlist: <span id='myList'>Empty</span> </p>
```

Comment: This is going to continually overwrite the previously set values. -1

Comment: Sort of, but not the way you've written it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild and the OP is using jQuery, so I need no reason to be using vanilla DOM for this at all.